# Deneb visuals color consistency with and without filters

Tags: powerbi, deneb

I have a stacked bar chart implemented in Deneb that takes colors for the series/legend from the "host" Power BI theme via pbiColorNominal.

What would be the recommended way for ensuring that colors for individual slices (legend/series) stay the same before and after applying filters (slicers) outside of Deneb visual?

Here is the chart with no filters applied:
[image]

And here is one with a couple of countries (BR, CA) removed:
[image]

Here is how a standard Stacked Bar Chart vs. Deneb after applying the same filters:
[image]

**Desired outcome: colors for the same countries (series) are stay in both cases.**

Theoretically, it's possible to dynamically build a mapping dimension with explicit color codes assigned to each series, join it with the dataset to visualize, and then pass it all into Deneb, but it's not clear how to make it consistent with colors used in the standard Power BI visuals on the same page.

Comment: it's strange as in my pbix color for each legend keeps same with or without filter/slicer. can it be the reason for pbi version? i may need see your pbix file for more details.

Comment: Hi Sia, thanks for the comment. That's the case for standard Power BI visuals, but not for Deneb (at least for me). 
Are you sure you are talking about Deneb visual?

Comment: One more contributing factor: in my visual, I use a Field Parameter as a series/legend column with the trick described there: https://github.com/deneb-viz/deneb/issues/238#issuecomment-1501033734
It's very possible that volatile values in the series break the logic of color assignments within Deneb, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Re: field parameters - just tested it with a direct column instead of Field Parameter, and it has the same issue.

Comment: Hi Vlad, i have missed the information of "Deneb". But based on your image i think the second visual of "stacked bar chart" can do same thing with colors keep same with or without slicer.

Comment: And for the Deneb visual i may need to see your pbix file to see more details.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2e5wciyb2ddhazv/FP.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Hi Vlad, i cannot open the file. sorry cannot help you. but i think you can try the second visual of "stacked bar chart".

Comment: Sorry, I assume that you were able to download the file, but it didn't open due to too high sensitivity settings. I just lowered it and updated the file. Can you try again please? 

Anyways, my question is about how to manage colors for Deneb visuals, so they stay consistent when external filters/slicers are applied.

Comment: Daniel Marh-Patrick answered to this question in his github issue tracker: https://github.com/deneb-viz/deneb/issues/296 In short, there is no ideal solution to this problem, but there is a couple of workarounds that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have consistency across your application, the best way is to store the colors as an attribute for your Geog (countries or regions). It will become a field into PBI.

You need to get it into your dataset and then use it within your code. Here is the encoding part:

```
"color": {
      "field": "Country Dimension",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "range": {
          "field": "Color of Country"
        }
      }
    }
```

I differentiated the "country" and the "color of country" because the field of the color object will be used in the legend.

You may use a more compact way if the country field is used somewhere else:

```
    "xOffset": {
      "field": "Country"
    },
    "color": {"field": "Color of Country"}
```

If you do not want to create any additional field, you will need to code like the following:

```
"color": {
      "field": "Country",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "domain": [
          your values of country
        ],
        "range": [
         your colors in the same order as the values
        ]
      },
```